# Obtaining maven dependency tree from project root of all child modules

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have my project defined like so:

```
foo
|
 - bar
 - baz
 - qux
```

The artifact type of the `foo` module is POM and it is the root module for the project. If I run the following mvn dependency tree command:

`mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=graphml -DoutputFile=dependency.graphml -Dincludes=com.foo`

It generates a dependency tree for ***each individual*** module, and in the case of the root module `foo`, it is empty as there are no dependencies. Is there a way to calculate a synthesised dependency tree from `foo` for all child modules so that there is 1 output for `foo`, which are the dependencies for all child modules? In this case, you can see I have excluded external dependencies `-Dincludes=com.foo`. There are dependencies between the 3 child modules above.

Comment: Are there dependencies between bar, baz, and qux? If those are independent projects then I'm not sure if there's a straightforward way to combine the their dependency trees. Consider if bar and baz depend on different versions of a library.

Comment: Yes there are dependencies between the child modules on each other.